# Need a little help understanding Node.js behavior. Why does a koa server respond synchronously to two simultaneous requests from the same browser?

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, firefox, asynchronous, koa

So I am just to trying to write a hello-world server with koa and koa-router. This is my code.

```
const Koa = require('koa')
const Router = require('koa-router')

const timeout = (ms) => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms))
const timestamp = () => {
    const d = new Date()
    return `${d.getUTCMinutes()}:${d.getUTCSeconds()}`
}
let req = 0

const app = new Koa()

app.use(async (ctx, next) => {
    ctx.state.req = req
    console.log(`URL: ${ctx.url}  time: ${timestamp()} request: ${req++}`)
    await next()
})

const router = new Router()

router.get('/', async (ctx, next) => {
    ctx.body = {
        message: "Hello, World!"
    }
    await next()
})

router.get('/favicon.ico', async ctx => ctx )

router.get("/test", async ctx => ctx.body = "Just a test")

app.use(router.routes())
app.use(async ctx => {
    await timeout(10000)
    console.log(`Hit req: ${ctx.state.req}! time: ${timestamp()}`)
    ctx.body.message += "After the delay!"
})


app.listen(3000)
console.log(`Listening on port 3000`)
```

Now this is working perfectly for a single request from a single browser. Problem arises when I try to make a second request to `localhost:3000` from the same browser. The second request doesn't get registered (handled?) until the first request has been completed. This doesn't happen if I make a request to `/test` or use another browser to make the request. The behaviour is consistent for both Chrome and Firefox. Only exception is Firefox Quantum.

```
Listening on port 3000
URL: /  time: 47:5 request: 0
URL: /  time: 47:7 request: 1
Hit req: 0! time: 47:15
Hit req: 1! time: 47:17
URL: /  time: 47:21 request: 2
Hit req: 2! time: 47:31
URL: /  time: 47:31 request: 3
Hit req: 3! time: 47:41
URL: /  time: 58:14 request: 4
Hit req: 4! time: 58:24
URL: /  time: 58:47 request: 5
URL: /  time: 58:50 request: 6
Hit req: 5! time: 58:57
Hit req: 6! time: 59:0
```

Here request 0 and 1 are from two different browsers. As you can see, request 1, irrespective of request 0's status. Request 2 and 3 are made from same browser (either Chrome, Firefox or Opera, its same for each of them). Here request 3 only gets registered after the server has finished responding to request 2. Request 4 was an isolated request. Request 5 and 6 are from Firefox Quantum and it behaves as expected.

Comment: Maybe the browser only wanting to use a single connection? I thought the limit was higher than 1, though.

Comment: @Ryan what do you mean, TCP connection to the server? Even then, shouldn't browser be able to send more than one request on a connection via pipelining?

Comment: Yes, I mean a TCP connection. You’re correct that the browser should be able to send more than one request with pipelining even on a single connection, but are you sure that it is? I know that Firefox at least has removed its HTTP/1.1 pipelining preference with the advent of HTTP/2. Don’t know whether Chrome ever had it enabled by default either.

Comment: Problem is with calling await next instead of next() not with a browser

Comment: @DanielStaleiny But, as per the Koa docs, calling it with `await` is perfectly fine. Here I have stripped the code down to just minimum which makes the `await` seem redundant but I need it in my code since I want the control to flow upstream for each request. https://github.com/koajs/koa

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: Initial problem you had that server acted like synchonious server was caused by calling **await next()** in your middleware instead of **return next()**. When you change it to await it waits to resolve that promise and returns afterwards. meaning that you cannot proccess any more request because you are waiting to resolve first. hope this will help you to understand when to call next properly

put middleware on top of router as it should be

```
const Koa = require("koa");
const Router = require("koa-router");

const timeout = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));
const timestamp = () => {
  const d = new Date();
  return `${d.getUTCMinutes()}:${d.getUTCSeconds()}`;
};

let req = 0;

const app = new Koa();

app.use(async (ctx, next) => {
  ctx.state.req = req;
  console.log(`URL: ${ctx.url}  time: ${timestamp()} request: ${req++}`);
  return next();
});

const router = new Router();

router.get("/", async ctx => {
  ctx.body.message = ctx.body.message + " Hello, World!";
});

router.get("/favicon.ico", async ctx => ctx);

router.get("/test", async ctx => (ctx.body = "Just a test"));
app.use(async (ctx, next) => {
  await timeout(10000);
  console.log(`Hit req: ${ctx.state.req}! time: ${timestamp()}`);
  ctx.body = { message: "With the delay!" };
  return next();
});
app.use(router.routes());

app.listen(3000);
console.log(`Listening on port 3000`);
```

and response in console. Result as expected and I called multiple request same and different browser and it work. Everything was async and delayed.

```
Listening on port 3000
URL: /  time: 11:56 request: 0
URL: /  time: 11:58 request: 1
URL: /  time: 12:0 request: 2
Hit req: 0! time: 12:6
Hit req: 1! time: 12:8
Hit req: 2! time: 12:10
URL: /  time: 12:10 request: 3
URL: /favicon.ico  time: 12:11 request: 4
URL: /  time: 12:19 request: 5
Hit req: 3! time: 12:20
Hit req: 4! time: 12:21
URL: /favicon.ico  time: 12:21 request: 6
Hit req: 5! time: 12:29
URL: /  time: 12:29 request: 7
Hit req: 6! time: 12:31
Hit req: 7! time: 12:39
```

What I did was to change order of the middleware because you had it after hitting a get route '/'. change next() correctly and everything works. 
I had to define message in middleware instead.

/**** old message ****/

router get doesn't have (ctx, next ) but has ctx only. only middleware and params has ctx and next parsed.
remove next and await next() and it should work
[koa router docs](https://github.com/alexmingoia/koa-router#routerparamparam-middleware--router)

Comment: Wait what do you mean? All the examples in the router use next.

Comment: @KidCoder: I’m pretty sure `await next()` isn’t correct. You use `next()` when *not* returning a promise. (All async functions return promises.) Probably isn’t breaking anything either though.